# ripple.js giving error on running the application on Visual Studio

Tags: ripple, visual-studio-code

I am running my application with ripple and it gives 2 error prompts before going to my application and paralelly in javascript, it gives below error. Please find screenshots as error prompt. I am running my code using visual studio 15 community version. I also tried compiling my code with ionic serve.

```
Ripple :: Environment Warming Up (Tea. Earl Grey. Hot.)
ripple.js (37,13091)
Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check     http://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.
ripple.js (50,29364)
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
ripple.js (50,29364)
cordova :: Initialization Finished (Make it so.)
ripple.js (37,13091)
HTML1300: Navigation occurred
index.html
Current window: http://localhost:4400/index.html
missing exec:Keyboard.init
ripple.js (40,29735)

ripple.js (40,29783)
   [ ]

TypeError: Cannot read property 'init' of undefined
ripple.js (40,29801)
   TypeError: Cannot read property 'init' of undefined ...

TypeError: Cannot read property 'init' of undefined
at module.exports.exec (http://localhost:4400/ripple/assets/ripple.js:40:29690)
at null.<anonymous> (http://localhost:4400/plugins/ionic-plugin-keyboard/www/android/keyboard.js:36:5)
at Channel.fire (http://localhost:4400/cordova.js:820:23)
at http://localhost:4400/cordova.js:1275:28
at f (http://localhost:4400/cordova.js:692:33)
at Channel.fire (http://localhost:4400/cordova.js:820:23)
at http://localhost:4400/cordova.js:1262:32
at onScriptLoadingComplete (http://localhost:4400/cordova.js:1731:5)
at scriptLoadedCallback (http://localhost:4400/cordova.js:1748:13)
at HTMLScriptElement.<anonymous> (http://localhost:4400/cordova.js:1702:17)
ripple.js (40,29816)
Keyboard
ripple.js (48,14754)
init
ripple.js (48,14775)
missing exec:Keyboard.close
ripple.js (40,29735)

ripple.js (40,29783)
[ ]

TypeError: Cannot read property 'close' of undefined
ripple.js (40,29801)
TypeError: Cannot read property 'close' of undefined ...

TypeError: Cannot read property 'close' of undefined
at module.exports.exec     (http://localhost:4400/ripple/assets/ripple.js:40:29690)
at Function.Keyboard.close (http://localhost:4400/plugins/ionic-plugin-keyboard/www/android/keyboard.js:16:5)
at Object.ionic.keyboard.hide (http://localhost:4400/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:3647:32)
at http://localhost:4400/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:43426:61
at Scope.$emit (http://localhost:4400/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:23474:33)
at Object.switcher.emit (http://localhost:4400/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:46814:27)
at Object.switcher.transition (http://localhost:4400/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:46672:22)
at http://localhost:4400/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:48301:16
at http://localhost:4400/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:46550:25
at Object.switcher.render     (http://localhost:4400/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:46639:23)
ripple.js (40,29816)
Keyboard
ripple.js (48,14754)
close
ripple.js (48,14775)
cordova :: Native back button handler was detached.
ripple.js (37,13091)
missing exec:Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar
ripple.js (40,29735)
true
ripple.js (40,29783)
[ ]

TypeError: Cannot read property 'hideKeyboardAccessoryBar' of undefined
 ripple.js (40,29801)
TypeError: Cannot read property 'hideKeyboardAccessoryBar' of undefined ...

TypeError: Cannot read property 'hideKeyboardAccessoryBar' of undefined
at module.exports.exec     (http://localhost:4400/ripple/assets/ripple.js:40:29690)
at Function.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar     (http://localhost:4400/plugins/ionic-plugin-    keyboard/www/android/keyboard.js:12:5)
at http://localhost:4400/js/app.js:32:32
at Array.<anonymous> (http://localhost:4400/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:44991:19)
at onPlatformReady (http://localhost:4400/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:2447:24)
at Channel.fire (http://localhost:4400/cordova.js:820:23)
at http://localhost:4400/cordova.js:229:49
ripple.js (40,29816)
Keyboard
ripple.js (48,14754)
hideKeyboardAccessoryBar
ripple.js (48,14775)
Ripple :: Environment Warming Up (Tea. Earl Grey. Hot.)
ripple.js (37,13091)
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
favicon.ico (0,0)
Current window: http://localhost:4400/index.html?enableripple=cordova-3.0.0-NexusGalaxy
Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check http://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.
ripple.js (50,29364)
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
ripple.js (50,29364)
cordova :: Initialization Finished (Make it so.)
ripple.js (37,13091)
HTML1300: Navigation occurred
index.html
Current window: http://localhost:4400/index.html
missing exec:Keyboard.init
ripple.js (40,29735)

ripple.js (40,29783)
[ ]

TypeError: Cannot read property 'init' of undefined
ripple.js (40,29801)
TypeError: Cannot read property 'init' of undefined ...

TypeError: Cannot read property 'init' of undefined
at module.exports.exec    (http://localhost:4400/ripple/assets/ripple.js:40:29690)
at null.<anonymous> (http://localhost:4400/plugins/ionic-plugin-     keyboard/www/android/keyboard.js:36:5)
at Channel.fire (http://localhost:4400/cordova.js:820:23)
at http://localhost:4400/cordova.js:1275:28
at f (http://localhost:4400/cordova.js:692:33)
at Channel.fire (http://localhost:4400/cordova.js:820:23)
at http://localhost:4400/cordova.js:1262:32
at onScriptLoadingComplete (http://localhost:4400/cordova.js:1731:5)
at scriptLoadedCallback (http://localhost:4400/cordova.js:1748:13)
at HTMLScriptElement.<anonymous> (http://localhost:4400/cordova.js:1702:17)
ripple.js (40,29816)
Keyboard
ripple.js (48,14754)
init
ripple.js (48,14775)
missing exec:Keyboard.close
ripple.js (40,29735)

ripple.js (40,29783)
[ ]

TypeError: Cannot read property 'close' of undefined
ripple.js (40,29801)
TypeError: Cannot read property 'close' of undefined ...

TypeError: Cannot read property 'close' of undefined
    at module.exports.exec     (http://localhost:4400/ripple/assets/ripple.js:40:29690)
at Function.Keyboard.close (http://localhost:4400/plugins/ionic-plugin-    keyboard/www/android/keyboard.js:16:5)
at Object.ionic.keyboard.hide      (http://localhost:4400/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:3647:32)
at http://localhost:4400/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:43426:61
at Scope.$emit (http://localhost:4400/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:23474:33)
at Object.switcher.emit (http://localhost:4400/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:46814:27)
at Object.switcher.transition (http://localhost:4400/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:46672:22)
at http://localhost:4400/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:48301:16
at http://localhost:4400/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:46550:25
at Object.switcher.render (http://localhost:4400/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:46639:23)
ripple.js (40,29816)
Keyboard
ripple.js (48,14754)
 close
ripple.js (48,14775)
cordova :: Native back button handler was detached.
ripple.js (37,13091)
missing exec:Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar
ripple.js (40,29735)
true
ripple.js (40,29783)
[ ]

TypeError: Cannot read property 'hideKeyboardAccessoryBar' of undefined
ripple.js (40,29801)
TypeError: Cannot read property 'hideKeyboardAccessoryBar' of undefined ...

TypeError: Cannot read property 'hideKeyboardAccessoryBar' of undefined
at module.exports.exec  (http://localhost:4400/ripple/assets/ripple.js:40:29690)
at Function.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar (http://localhost:4400/plugins/ionic-plugin-keyboard/www/android/keyboard.js:12:5)
at http://localhost:4400/js/app.js:32:32
at Array.<anonymous> (http://localhost:4400/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:44991:19)
at onPlatformReady (http://localhost:4400/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:2447:24)
at Channel.fire (http://localhost:4400/cordova.js:820:23)
at http://localhost:4400/cordova.js:229:49
ripple.js (40,29816)
Keyboard
ripple.js (48,14754)
hideKeyboardAccessoryBar
ripple.js (48,14775)
missing exec:Keyboard.close
ripple.js (40,29735)

ripple.js (40,29783)
[ ]

TypeError: Cannot read property 'close' of undefined
ripple.js (40,29801)
TypeError: Cannot read property 'close' of undefined ...

TypeError: Cannot read property 'close' of undefined
at module.exports.exec (http://localhost:4400/ripple/assets/ripple.js:40:29690)
at Function.Keyboard.close (http://localhost:4400/plugins/ionic-plugin-keyboard/www/android/keyboard.js:16:5)
at Object.ionic.keyboard.hide (http://localhost:4400/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:3647:32)
at http://localhost:4400/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:43426:61
at Scope.$emit (http://localhost:4400/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:23474:33)
at Object.switcher.emit (http://localhost:4400/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:46814:27)
at Object.switcher.transition (http://localhost:4400/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:46672:22)
at http://localhost:4400/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:48301:16
at http://localhost:4400/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:46550:25
at Object.switcher.render (http://localhost:4400/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:46639:23)
ripple.js (40,29816)
Keyboard
ripple.js (48,14754)
close
ripple.js (48,14775)
missing exec:Keyboard.close
ripple.js (40,29735)

ripple.js (40,29783)
[ ]

TypeError: Cannot read property 'close' of undefined
ripple.js (40,29801)
TypeError: Cannot read property 'close' of undefined ...

TypeError: Cannot read property 'close' of undefined
at module.exports.exec (http://localhost:4400/ripple/assets/ripple.js:40:29690)
at Function.Keyboard.close (http://localhost:4400/plugins/ionic-plugin-keyboard/www/android/keyboard.js:16:5)
at Object.ionic.keyboard.hide (http://localhost:4400/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:3647:32)
at http://localhost:4400/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:43426:61
at Scope.$emit (http://localhost:4400/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:23474:33)
at Object.switcher.emit (http://localhost:4400/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:46814:27)
at Object.switcher.transition (http://localhost:4400/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:46672:22)
at http://localhost:4400/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:48301:16
at http://localhost:4400/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:46550:25
at Object.switcher.render (http://localhost:4400/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:46639:23)
ripple.js (40,29816)
Keyboard
ripple.js (48,14754)
close
ripple.js (48,14775)
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Which device platform are you targeting with your app (e.g. iOS or Android)?

Answer (score 1):

In app.js, replace the following line of code

```
cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
```

with

```
if (cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar) {
    cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
}
```

Regards